# How to use the same toggle comment with two different ID/Classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I want to make an expanding sidebar, I was able to make the sidebar expand but but I need to cover the original button that was pressed.

I would like to have an area at the side where I can click to close the sidebar.

I'm almost there. The problem i'm having is that the close id when clicked does not seem to trigger the toggle.

here is my code

```js
$("#icon-menu-mobile,#exit").each(function() {
  $(this).click(function() {
    var effect = 'slide';
    var options = 'left';
    var duration = 500;

    $('#panel').toggle(effect, options, duration);
  });
});
```

```css
#panel {

  position: absolute;

  top: 0px;

  width: 100%;

  height: 100%;

  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

  display: none;

  z-index: 999;

}

.panelcontent {

  position: relative;

  top: 50px;

  width: 70%;

  height: 100%;

  background-color: #cccccc;

  float: left;

}

#icon-menu-mobile {

  width: 36px;

  height: 30px;

  cursor: pointer;

  font-size: 24px;

}

#icon-menu-mobile,

#exit {

  position: static;

  float: right;

  width: 30%;

  height: 100%;

  cursor: pointer;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>


  <span id="icon-menu-mobile">
 ☰      
</span>

  <div id="panel">
    <div class="panelcontent">
      Some text here to fill it out

    </div>
    <div id="exit">
      Click here to exit
    </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

As you can see after clicking the burger menu you can't close it with the side close button.

I'm guessing that the toggle only works from the first id clicked and that id needs to be clicked again to toggle again.

Is there a way to have two id's activate the same toggle?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgGPrm

I think you were attaching the same event to both, so it wouldn't slide to the opposite direction, i've split it up into:

```
$("#icon-menu-mobile").click(function() {
    var effect = 'slide';
    var options = 'left';
    var duration = 500;

    $('#panel').toggle(effect, options, duration);
});

$("#exit").click(function() {
    var effect = 'slide';
    var options = 'right';
    var duration = 500;

    $('#panel').toggle(effect, options, duration);
});
```

EDIT: actually upon further inspection, it doesn't seem to matter if they are together or not. the thing that fixed it was actually including jQuery-UI in my codepen. are you sure you are properly including jQuery-UI? otherwise you get an error after the initial slide, which prevents the second slide from working

Comment: I think I do. is this it? 
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Very odd, the demo works fine but on my site it only opens. The close does not work...

Comment: try `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
`

Comment: awesome! glad I could help